# import of file failed not enough space

Tags: google-compute-engine

I don't have a tech background, but decided to create a Google Compute Engine instance to be able to create a 1.6GB database. I use PostgreSQL (Pgadmin3) to access the database on GCE. It has been working fine so far, but now I am trying to import a new file and am getting the error message

> "Panic: could not write to file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.1293": No space left on the device"

I looked at the documentation in Google for resizing the disk. I did a df -h in SSH and got

```
/dev/sda1       9.8G  9.2G   16M 100% /
```

I also did

```
sudo lsblk --output NAME,size,state
NAME   SIZE STATE
sda     20G running
 └─sda1  10G
```

So then I did

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/disk/by-id/google-myddisk-part1
resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The filesystem is already 2620928 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As this is the root disk you have to reboot the instance. It should then automatically resize the disk during boot. Please check details here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd

Comment: Thanks I think this worked, but now I am having trouble connecting to the instance via ssh or even telnetting to the instance. And I am pretty sure the firewall is not the problem.

Comment: You can check the serial port in the console. It should display all messages while booting.

Comment: Thanks. What I get is this:


`SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20161221_130212-google)
Total RAM Size = 0x000000006cc00000 = 1740 MiB
CPUs found: 1     Max CPUs supported: 1
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=41943040 = 20480 MiB
drive 0x000f4780: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=41943040
Booting from Hard Disk 0...`